# make uipickerview appear between cells when touched cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipickerview

I like to implement UI like this screen.

as you see, when I touch a specific cell, pickerview appears at the bottom of that cell.
and it sits between two cell. and pickerview doesn't seem to be a subview of cell.

How do I implement this? I don't know where to start...

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert a new `cell` which contains a `UIPickerView` when user tap on a `cell` by using this method -

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

Also for this you need to handle your `data structure` carefully by which you are populating your `UITableView`.

You can checkout this repo, it might help you - 
https://github.com/saadnib/InsertPickerInTableView

Comment: I'm facing the problem and I did the same thing as that project, but I'm having the same problem where the animation isn't looking right.