# IOS UIPickerView - add to Static table dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

Is it possible to add a uipickerview / uidateview dynamically into a static uitableview?

I basically want the same functionality as the IOS calendar inputs as requested here - [iOS Show UIPickerView between UITableViewCells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073316/ios-show-uipickerview-between-uitableviewcells)
but as I have a static table I don't have any of the available table methods to apply my insertion code to - so I'm struggling!

Answer (score 2):

Apple sample code [Datecell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/datecell/Introduction/Intro.html) has a perfect example on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to customise the static table view controller dynamically you can overwrite table view delegate methods like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    // You can change the number of sections here...
    return [super numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // You can change the number of rows here...
    return [super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // You can change the returning cell of static table view here...
    return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```