# Non-appearing inline UIPickerView in prototype UITableViewCell in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipickerview

thanks for reading!

I'm struggling to get an inline UIPickerView to **appear** in a UITableViewCell as defined on a storyboard prototype cell.  This file implements tableview and pickerview datasource and delegate mandatory methods (not fully shown).  I am happier about my data structures, but the iOS GUI stuff I find harder in Objective C.

My data array holds info for 12 cells. When cell 0 is pressed cells 1 and 2 are expanded. Similarly 4&5 expand when 3 is pressed etc. This all works fine by adjusting the height of the cells.

I can't understand why when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is given the appropriate UIPickerView-containing cells at the picker view indexrows, does it not display them.

Header snippit (matching storyboard's reuseidentifier and tag)

```
#define kPickerTag      100
static NSString *kPickerCellID = @"pickerCellID";
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPickerView *pickerView;
```

Relevant functions:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
   ...
   self.pickerView = (UIPickerView *)[tableTimes viewWithTag:kPickerTag];
   self.pickerView.dataSource = self; //The pickerView object in storyboard needs datasource+delegate which is this file too
   self.pickerView.delegate = self;
   ...
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   ...
   //the case which returns UIPickerView rows
   pickerCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kPickerCellID];
   self.pickerView = (UIPickerView *)[pickerCell viewWithTag:kPickerTag];
   return pickerCell;
   ...
}
```

Any help is **much** appreciated!

PS I have read the following and still can't understand it:
Apple's DateCell (ad infinitum!)
[iOS Show UIPickerView between UITableViewCells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073316/ios-show-uipickerview-between-uitableviewcells)
http://masteringios.com/blog/2013/10/31/ios-7-in-line-uidatepicker/3/
http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9482

Comment: It's impossible to tell with the information you've given. Is that case being called? Does it return a valid cell? Is the cell big enough to display a picker view? Do you see anything at all, or just a blank cell?

Comment: Yes the case is being called, I checked that. Also the cell is valid, I omitted a check from the above code for clarity. Also The cell is big enough. I did have a screen shot but apparently I can't upload it as I'm a new member to stackoverflow.  Yes, only a blank cell appears. Let me know if there's anything extra I should show :/

Comment: I don't know what else you could have done that would make it not work. I tried dragging a UIPickerView into a prototype cell, and it showed up just fine.

Comment: I figured out a part of it.  You can't set self.pickerView.delegate = self in viewDidLoad for prototype cells, because they aren't created until cellforrowatindexpath asks for them.  So setting delegate/datasource there made it work.